# Uiaotomator.bat file is not open, Opened only for millisecond

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

My uiaotomator.bat isn't open, whenever I clicked on my bat file it open for millisecond & then disappeared. How do i open this file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might have encountered an error during running, try opening instead your command line and run the bat file from there, you will see the error it encountered.

```
cmd> uiaotomator.bat
.... some message here..
... or error message will be displayed ...
```

Comment: Error message displayed: 'uiaotomator.bat' is not recognized ................      but I'm already set the paths

Comment: what error? atleast you know what is the error now and from that you can move forward to get the solution

Comment: 'uiaotomator.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file....................                                                                  but I'm already set the paths

Comment: my bad, where are you running your bat file? which device/os? bat file can be run directly in windows os command line

Comment: I just want to open my Automator, I'm using the android emulator